# icsharpcode.texteditor MouseDown or MouseUp event doesn't work

Tags: icsharpcode

```
   private void textEditorConrol_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
            {

            }
        }
```

This event does not work out when i click.

I'm using the same event for 4 controls and I have a problem only with this component